# PHP require files

Tags: php

I am currently working on a website and the nav looks like this

[image]

I have primarilly made a page template that is shared by all the pages.The picture follows shows how i tried to break down the template into different pieces.

[image]

now I have to keep all files in the main directory. I can't put related pages for example all listing pages in listing folder or all download pages in download folder etc because it can't access the require files. I have tried using **..** operator but the template is so nested that it is not helping either.

My question is what strategy do I use so that I can use template pieces yet all related files can be grouped in folders rather than keeping all files in the main directory. That looks really messy

Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You should not put all files in your main directory which will look messy and confusing.

Better you put required files in their respective folders and call them properly.

In index.php-> its okay how you have included files.

But in init.php -> you don't need to write folder name "core" as init.php is already inside core folder.
So simply use

```
require('connect.php');
```

Similarly in header.php

```
 require('logo.php');
```

And in footer.php

```
require('counter.php');
```

If you have any problem, plz let me know.